# Does Kinesis encrypt its data at rest?

Tags: security, amazon-kinesis

Are Kinesis messages encrypted when they are stored on AWS?

What mechanism is used to persistently store the messages?

Comment: What is Kinesis? Maybe you could fill out the aws-kinesis tag wiki a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are Kinesis messages encrypted when they are stored on AWS?

Encryption mechanisms of a [created Amazon Kinesis stream application](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/faqs/)  follows the same principles as for any other application you create on AWS. So here are the questions you need to ask yourself:

1. **Do you control the encryption method and the entire KMI?**

In this case,  you are responsible for the encrryption/decryption process as well as the  management, and use of keys of which AWS has no access.

2. **Do you control the encryption method and provide the KMI management layer while AWS provides you the KMI storage component?**

In this case, your cryptographic keys are stored in the
AWS environment but are not ccessible to AWS' employees. You will need to use [AWS CloudHSM](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/).

3. **Do you decide to let AWS controls the encryption method and the entire KMI?**

In this scenario, AWS manages everything automatically on your behalf: meaning that **yes**, Kinesis messages are **encrypted**  when  stored on AWS.

## Practical solution for you:

To avoid troubles, you may use the third option: let AWS do it on your behalf. This corresponds to the third listed case above. For this purpose, the simplest and easiest way for you is to use **[Amazon Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/)** which  *can  batch, compress, and **encrypt the data before loading it**, minimizing the amount of storage used at the destination and increasing security.*

> What mechanism is used to persistently store the messages?

The data retention period  is configurable in hourly increments from 24 (the default retention period) to 168 hours (7 days), and requestable via the Streams Limits form ([*Amazon Kinesis Streams Limits*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)). Nevertheless, you can  persist data to Amazon S3 from Amazon Kinesis Streams using **AWS Lambda** and **Amazon Kinesis Firehose**. You can find here a step by step practical example: [***Persist Streaming Data to Amazon S3 using Amazon Kinesis Firehose and AWS Lambda***](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2MUQB5PRWU36K/Persist-Streaming-Data-to-Amazon-S3-using-Amazon-Kinesis-Firehose-and-AWS-Lambda)

Answer (score 5):

[Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) is an umbrella name for three underlying AWS products:

1. [Amazon Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/)
2. [Amazon Kinesis Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/analytics/)
3. [Amazon Kinesis Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/)

Kinesis Streams is a foundational component of the other two products, which leverage Kinesis Streams to provide value-add capabilities.

At the time of this writing, Kinesis Firehose can be used to send data to either an Amazon S3 bucket, to an Amazon Redshift table, or to the Amazon Elasticsearch service (or to any combination of these distinations).

As [Billal BEGUERADJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5906918/billal-begueradj) mentioned in his answer, Amazon Kinesis Firehose offers an option to encrypt data at rest in the destination data store that the data is streamed to via Kinesis streams.  The encryption happens as part of storing the data into the destination. For more on this, please refer to the FAQ "what kind of encryption can I use?" in the [Kinesis Firehose FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/faqs/).

Data sent through a Kinesis Steam is retained by the stream for a configurable duration. At the time of this writing, the default is 24 hours, with an option to extend the duration to up to 7 days. [citation](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/faqs/)

While the data is retained by the stream, it does not appear to be encrypted at rest, although the Amazon Kinesis Streams documentation does not seem to specifically address this question.  So presumably even if you are using Kinesis Firehose with encryption enabled, there is still data persisted at rest for 24 hours on the underlying stream (transparent to you as an end user of this managed service) that is not encrypted at rest.

Similarly if you are just using a Kinesis stream directly, data is not encrypted at rest.

To overcome the lack of encryption at rest, you would need to use client side encryption / decryption in the producer and consumer applications respectively.